# Как правильно позиционировать блоки кирпичной кладки?

Tags: css, css3

При расположении изображений в стиле "masonry" постоянно то сбиваются расстояния между ними, то по высоте они размещаются не в одну линию. Использую `display: grid` для такого размещения, и при необходимости задать отступы между изображениями, даже несмотря на то, что они пропорциональны в размерах, они перестают выравниваться по одной границе (по высоте).

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  align-items: end;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "a b" "c b";
}
img:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: a;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: c;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://cs6.pikabu.ru/avatars/716/v716268-731801248.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AAUvwngWFcWm7u0yMSpdBO8beLJ-p1VDlS2gSwGc2FR57w=s100-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"/>
  <img src="https://chatovka.net/avatar/534218.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Есть ли возможность вообще в css избежать такой проблемы?

Comment: Можете посмотреть пример выполнения [тут](https://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/yKJGb) или на гридах [тут](https://codepen.io/iamsaief/pen/jObaoKo)

Comment: @Alexandr, спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете использовать  `align-items: stretch`, чтобы растянуть вертикальную картинку. Сейчас у нее пропорции 1:2, т.е. не учтен gap в 10px

Comment: Если искажение небольшое, то, думаю, вполне подойдет. Спасибо.